# Resolving gem version incompatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am new to Ruby, Rails and gem management. One thing what I have noticed is that whenever I run `bundle install` (even within the project directory) it seems to install gems which affects other gem based Rails projects too.

For instance, assume that after running `bundle install` within one gem based Rail project (which installs a bunch of gems from the gemfile) I run into gem incompatibility issues. Now, these issues will manifest in all the other gem based projects too and will present themselves everytime I attempt to `rackup`

My questions are:
1) Is there a way to localize this damage (gem version incompatibility) to the current project and not have other projects affected?
2) Is there a good way to obtain a compatible set of gems or is the only way to look at the gem dependencies on a gem-by-gem basis (look at the tree) and figure out the compatible ones? I seem to be wasting a lot of time on this and if I fix one something else seems to break.

Please let me know what I'm missing here or point me to resources.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv or similar?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu VM and used ruby2.3-dev and ruby-dev packages to install ruby. How do I know if I'm using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: You're not; you'd have to install them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing use of [`bundle exec`](http://bundler.io/v1.14/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

> Description
>   This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the Gemfile(5) available to require in Ruby programs.
>
> Essentially, if you would normally have run something like `rspec spec/my_spec.rb`, and you want to use the gems specified in the Gemfile(5) and installed via bundle install(1), you should run `bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec.rb`.

`bundle install` will install gems to `$GEM_HOME` which is shared by any apps using the same ruby and can result in multiple versions of the same gem being installed (this is expected and normal). If you don't then also use `bundle exec` to load only the gem versions specified in your Gemfile you can get incompatibility errors or unexpected behavior as ruby doesn't know which version of a particular gem to require.

---

RVM, rbenv, and other ruby version managers are useful tools for both isolating gems per project (which isn't really necessary when also using bundler) and for allowing multiple ruby versions to be installed on the same machine (which is not handled by bundler and can be very useful when developing multiple apps with different ruby version requirements).

Comment: One thing the can add confusion here is that the `rails` command (as of rails 3 I think) automatically invokes bundler so `rails server` is equivalent to `bundle exec rails server`. This can give the impression that no other use of bundler is required after a `bundle install` until you start using non-rails executables included with other gems.

Comment: I am probably getting caught up in the language. Sorry, English isn't my first language. You said -  "If you don't then also use bundle exec to load only the gem versions specified in your Gemfile you can get incompatibility errors or unexpected behavior as ruby doesn't know which version of a particular gem to require". So, is the expectation to run `bundle exec` and not `bundle install` or to run `bundle exec` after running `bundle install`? Also, available to require in Ruby programs in the description implies the `require` keyword?

Comment: `bundle install` to install gems, then `bundle exec` to run a command with only the gems listed in your Gemfile available to `require` via the Ruby `require` keyword.

Comment: So, if I want to run a rails project locally then the preferred approach is to  `bundle exec rackup` to ensure that the updates to the central gem repo don't affect my current project?